# Regex for words with no doubled characters and within a string length

Tags: regex

Every time I need to use a regex I realize I've forgotten everything about them.

I am trying to match all words that have only lowercase alphanumeric characters AND do not have doubled alphanumeric characters AND are also within {10,12} characters long.

Now, to figure out if a character is followed by the same character, I would do `(.)\1`. To see if a word is within 10 and 12 characters I do `{10,12}`. To grab only lowercase letters and the digits, I do `[0-9a-z]`.

But how do I link them together?

Cheers!

PS: this will be running on a fairly large NLP xml (100mb+), so I would appreciate it if the regex wasn't the slowest alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will do what you want: -

```
/\b(?:([a-z0-9])(?!\1)){10,12}\b/
```

**Explanation: -**

```
\b   // Word boundary
(?:
    ([a-z0-9])  // Match lowercase letters or digit
    (?!\1)      // Not followed by the same digit as before
){10,12}        // 10 to 12 times.
\b   // Word boundary
```

Comment: This will match blahblahbl in blahblahblaa.

Comment: +1 - Didn't see your answer while typing mine but you did get there first. Just need to add word boundaries, which I had forgotten too.

Comment: @Jeff-Meadows. Ah! Just a matter of word boundary.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one, although I'm not sure there won't be a better way...

```
/\b(?:([a-z0-9])(?!\1)){10,12}\b/
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt:

```
 (\b(?![0-9a-z]*([0-9a-z])\2)[0-9a-z]{10,12}\b)
```

(We have to use a lookahead, and some kind of boundary is usually very important for it to function properly. Hence `\b`).

At the time of writing, another answer has a false positive, matching a *part* of `eoeuaoarounn`